# Getting empty object on importing from transpiled ES6 code

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

The source code is written in ES6 and transpiled to ES5 using babel and webpack, and it looks like this:

**src/2.js**

```
export default {
   ...
}
```

**src/1.js**

```
import 2 from './2.js'
export default {
    ...
}
```

`1.js` is the main entry script for webpack. Here's the webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'entry': './src/1.js',
  'module': {
    'loaders': [{
      'test': /\.js$/,
      'exclude': /node_modules/,
      'loader': 'react-hot-loader/webpack'
    }, {
      'test': /\.js$/,
      'exclude': /node_modules/,
      'loader': 'babel-loader'
    }]
  },
  'output': {
    'path': path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    'publicPath': '/',
    'filename': 'index.js'
  }
}
```

The ES5 transpiled file `index.js` is then published as an npm module, say 'example_module'.

Now, in a different app when I do:

```
import exampleModule from `example-module`;
console.log(exampleModule)  // <-- empty object
```

I get an empty object when trying to import the module.

I seem to understand(not sure) that the transpiled file is meant to be used inside a script tag in native ES5 environment and cannot be imported in ES6 code.

The question is, how should I tweak the build process so that the module can be used in both ES5 and ES6 environment?

Comment: Are you really trying to name your import the number `2`?

Comment: @1252748 it's just an example

Comment: @MichaelJungo yeah looks like it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you `import exampleModule from 'example-module';` it goes looking by default in your `node_modules/` folder of the `different-app` project.

You have two possibilities:

1. Use webpack and [aliases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) to tell webpack to get `example-module` from another absolute folder.
2. Link `example-module` with your favorite package manager ([yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link)/[npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)) to your `node_modules` folder.

I would personally go with option #2.